# Uncaught exception from servlet java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:mysql:///iworks_db

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am working on a Java Google App Engine app, and when I deploy my app and open it on my browser I get the above error. iworks_db is the name of my database, and for some reason my app fails to connect to it. I'm using the guide found here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine.

My createConnectionPool method:

```
private DataSource createConnectionPool() {
    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();

    config.setJdbcUrl(String.format("jdbc:mysql:///%s", DB_NAME));
    config.setUsername(DB_USER); 
    config.setPassword(DB_PASS); 
    config.setDriverClassName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver");// This line does NOT exist on the guide
                                                            // I added it because I was getting "failed 
                                                            // to get driver instance" error

    config.addDataSourceProperty("socketFactory", "com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("cloudSqlInstance", CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME);
    config.addDataSourceProperty("useSSL", "false");

    config.setMaximumPoolSize(5);

    config.setMinimumIdle(5);

    config.setConnectionTimeout(10000); // 10 seconds

    config.setIdleTimeout(600000); // 10 minutes

    config.setMaxLifetime(1800000); // 30 minutes

    DataSource pool = new HikariDataSource(config);

    return pool;
  }
```

The dependencies in my pom.xml file:

```
    <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL is a mysql url while your driver is HyperSQL DataBase (hsqldb). That is the reason you get the exception regarding not acceptable jdbcUrl.

Your DB is Google Cloud mysql, which I believe is the case as the rest of your code use mysql factory (com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory),  then change the driver class name to following:

```
 config.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
```

Also replace the hsldb maven dependency with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.18</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.14</version>
 </dependency>
```

The `com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory` is provided in the `mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8` maven artifact.

Update:

You could also try not to use the DriverClassName at all.

Try adding the above two dependencies and remove the setDriverClassName line.